# Installing PulseEffects on Ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, equalizer

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 for 3 weeks right now, and I don't have much knowledge installing apps and adding ppa sources.
I was searching for some **equalizer software** and it ends up by finding **PulseEffects**, but I don't find anywhere how to install it on Ubuntu 18.04.

Could anybody help me and show me step by step the installation procedure?

Answer (score 7):

## Installing PulseEffects

#### Ubuntu 18.04

These describtion is taken from [how-to install PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects --install-recommends
```

But be aware, these is 3rd party software.

#### Ubuntu 19.10 and Newer

Maintained inside Debian main repository by hosiet.

To install pulseeffects on latest Ubuntu systems, run:

```
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```

Comment: Note that the [repo](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu) advises to only use with `pulseaudio --version > 12`  and if you have a lower version to also install `pulseaudio` from their PPA using `sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio --install-recommends`

Comment: You are right for Ubuntu 18, will correct it. Ubuntu 20 has already pulseaudio 13.99.1.

Comment: @lucidbrot your suggestion worked for me, crackling stopped.
ubuntu 22.04 Dell xps15

Answer (score 1):

From [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/install-pulse-effects-ubuntu-ppa):

---

### PulseEffects is a Powerful GTK Audio Effects & Equalizer App for Linux

[image: Pulse Effects Main Window.png]

It is possible to install [PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and above, but there are a few caveats involved.

The latest version of PulseEffects is not (that I can find) yet packaged for Ubuntu. If you want to run the very latest build you will need to download the source code from Github and manually compile it.

An older version of the app is available via an engorged [third-party GNOME 3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/). As this personal package archive is chock-full of other apps, themes and libraries I recommend only downloading the PulseEffects package itself directly, rather than adding the PPA to your software sources.

**Update:** The app is now available as a Flatpak app via Flathub.

---

**Note:** visit the *OMG Ubuntu* article in the topmost link for more details, including direct downloads.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older version of pulseeffects which I happen to like:

https://launchpad.net/~yunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/gnome3
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulseeffects is also available in flatpack.

sudo flatpak install flathub com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command on your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseeffects
```